# Can Semaphore.acquire() throw InterruptedException due to a spurious wakeup?

Tags: java, semaphore, java.util.concurrent

A seemingly straightforward problem:  I have a [`java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), and I want to acquire a permit using [`acquire()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire()).

The `acquire()` method is specified to throw `InterruptedException` if the thread is interrupted:

> If the current thread:
>
> - has its interrupted status set on entry to this method; or
> - is interrupted while waiting for a permit,
>
> then InterruptedException is thrown and the current thread's interrupted status is cleared.

However, the usual pattern with methods that may throw `InterruptedException` is to call them in a loop, since threads can be subject to spurious wakeups that look the same as being interrupted.  For example, the [documentation for `Object.wait(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)) says:

> A thread can also wake up without being notified, interrupted, or timing out, a so-called spurious wakeup. While this will rarely occur in practice, applications must guard against it by testing for the condition that should have caused the thread to be awakened, and continuing to wait if the condition is not satisfied. In other words, waits should always occur in loops.

So the question is, is `Semaphore.acquire()` subject to the same kind of spurious wakeup?  The logical answer would be "no", but I can't find any evidence for that, and in fact the evidence seems to point in the other direction.

Looking at the [source for `Semaphore`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.java), it appears that it delegates the actual acquire to an [`AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html), which according to [its source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java) delegates to `LockSupport.park()`.

The [documentation for `LockSupport.park()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#park()) explicitly mentions spurious wakeup, but the implementation of `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireInterruptably()` appears to just check `Thread.interrupted()` and then throw `InterruptedException`.

So, unless I'm missing something (which is very possible), it appears that `Semaphore.acquire()` **can** throw `InterruptedException` spuriously?

Is that correct?  More importantly, is there anything I can do about that?  I could use `Semaphore.acquireUninterruptably()`, but I don't want an uninterruptable wait, just one that doesn't get interrupted spuriously.  Is there any alternative?

Comment: It is "spurious wakeup" not "spurious interrupt": "A thread can also wake up without being notified, interrupted, or timing out, a so-called spurious wakeup." There is no InterruptedException thrown during a spurious wakeup.

Comment: @SkipHead: So the thread wakes up, but the `interrupted` flag is not set?  That makes sense -- can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is "spurious wakeup" not "spurious interrupt": "A thread can also wake up without being notified, interrupted, or timing out, a so-called spurious wakeup." There is no InterruptedException thrown during a spurious wakeup. As you say in the comments: The thread wakes up but the interrupted flag is not set.

Answer (score 3):

I think if you think about the `Semaphore.acquire()` API, you'll realize that it's impossible for it to have a spurious wakeup, mainly because the caller would have no way to distinguish "spurious" for "normal", and therefore the method would be *useless*.

Comment: Agreed, and that's why I asked the question.  I assumed as much, and just went to check the code to validate my assumption, but I was unsettled because I seemed to find evidence that a spurious failure could occur, so I asked here to confirm.