# When should I worry about spurious wakeups when using java.util.concurrent classes

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I know that if I call `Object.wait()` I have to account for spurious wakeups so I should wrap the *wait* in a *while* loop that checks if my actual terminating condition was reached. But in cases where I use `java.util.concurrent.*` classes should I still worry about that?

I am using a *java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue* and I want to know if when I do `queue.take()` I should expect that sometimes *take()* will stop blocking because of a spurious wakeup (InterruptedException) and not because it actually read something from the queue. In other words, if spurious wakeups are a risk, I need to catch the InterruptedException INSIDE a while loop that actually checks for termination. If they are not, then I should probably leave InterruptedExceptions break the main-loop and stop processing when I get one

Or in code

```
@Override
public void run() {
  while(running()) {
    try {
       queue.take();
    } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
       log.warn("Spurious wakeup, ignore and try again");
    }
  }
}
```

vs

```
@Override
public void run() {
  try {
    while(running()) {
       queue.take();
    }
  } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
      log.error("Some other reason for InterruptedException, finish thread");
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CountDownLatch InterruptedException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168430/countdownlatch-interruptedexception)

Comment: From the first Answer of the linked Q: "An InterruptedException is basically a polite request for that thread to terminate. The thread should clean up and exit as soon as possible."

Comment: i don't think the question you point to is a duplicate of this one. My question is, should I worry about spurious wakeups when using java.util.concurrent.* classes? which should have a YES or NO answer. The linked question does gives me new information so thank you

Comment: You should worry and terminate the thread. The linked first Answer does answers this and CountDownLatch is java.util.concurrent as well.

Comment: The content of the waiting function for CountDownLatch.await() and BlockingQueue.take() are the same, so the same answer applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going off of this question: [Can Semaphore.acquire() throw InterruptedException due to a spurious wakeup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165030/can-semaphore-acquire-throw-interruptedexception-due-to-a-spurious-wakeup)

It appears that a spurious wakeup does not actually interrupt the thread, <strike>so it seems that you don't need to have the try/catch there</strike> (edit: for a spurious wakeup, that is. You still need to have it in case the waiting thread is actually interrupted).

According to the first answer there:

"It is "spurious wakeup" not "spurious interrupt": "A thread can also wake up without being notified, interrupted, or timing out, a so-called spurious wakeup." There is no InterruptedException thrown during a spurious wakeup. As you say in the comments: The thread wakes up but the interrupted flag is not set"

Comment: You have to handle the Interrupted Exception anyway.

Comment: That's true, I was only thinking about spurious wakeups, not other forms of interruption. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @user3580294 a wakeup is not a "form of interruption," at least, not as far as the Java programmer is concerned.  There may be something like "interruption" that happens in the JVM or in the operating system, but at the Java level, they are two different concepts.